# Kong for Web Apps

Tags: authentication, web-applications, kong

Here a newbie in [kong](https://getkong.org/). We have several web apps without authentication in different programming languages and environments.

Our idea is to protect each web app (the web user interface) by securing it with a login screen (single singn on). We want to use kong since APIs are going to be developed and should be protected by kong, too.

Ideally we can use our internal ldap server to manage user credentials.

My questions:

- Can we use kong to show up login screen for the web apps?
- Do we need to modify out web apps for that?
- How to make kong talk to ldap for getting user credentials?

Comment: A similar question was asked earlier here: https://github.com/Kong/kong/issues/1382  But there is no good answer yet. Any further insights here?

Answer (score 0):

For your questions

```
Can we use kong to show up login screen for the web apps?
```

There is no need to do that, for kong authorization most of the time you can send the details in header which kong will use to authenticate

```
Do we need to modify out web apps for that?
```

If you need to use the user info which Kong will pass in the header, then you need to modify your app to understand that.

```
How to make kong talk to ldap for getting user credentials?
```

You need to configure Kong server to connect to LDAP server. Details about that are provided on the [Kong LDAP Plugin page](http://Can%20we%20use%20kong%20to%20show%20up%20login%20screen%20for%20the%20web%20apps?%20Do%20we%20need%20to%20modify%20out%20web%20apps%20for%20that?%20How%20to%20make%20kong%20talk%20to%20ldap%20for%20getting%20user%20credentials?)

Comment: The question was about web apps with user interaction. This is why we need to show a login screen for the user. We'd like to use Kong as single product to care about login - in the API and the user interface. So there is a need to show up login screens.